# Bevel evenly without manual cleanup of geometry

Tags: bevel

I want to make a evenly spread bevel here:

[image]

[image]

But the geometry gives a problem:

[image]

Is there any way other then a manual cleanup to work around this?

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your object?

Comment: @moonboots yes, added!

Answer (score 0):

These vertices prevent the bevel from extending:

[image]

Here is what's happening:

[image]

If you press <kbd>C</kbd> while bevelling it will clamp the bevel, but you can't go beyond the vertices from what it seems. So if you want a round corner here you probably need a better topology.